# Solving equation with $n\log n$

Tags: time-complexity

Given a computer that takes 1 microsecond for an operation, I'm trying to find the amount of operations this computer can perform in one second, given an algorithm with complexity $O(n\log n)$. I've tried to solve it by the following ways but always get stuck. Note that one second equals $10^6$ microseconds.

### [image: What I've tried]

I've found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188637/how-can-i-solve-for-n-in-the-equation-n-log-n-c) post where it's stated that *"there is no simple way"* to solve that but I still want to ask here if there is any different approach to the question from a "computer science perspective".

Comment: There's no "computer science perspective", this is Numerical Mathematics for beginners. n = 10^6 / log n. Set n = 1,000,000. Evaluate the right side. Set n to the result. Evaluate the right side and repeat until the result doesn't change.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thank you! This works well for me. May I ask what the name of this method is? I'd like to study that and this seems like a good starting point ...

Comment: "Iterative Method".

Comment: If the complexity is $O(n \log n)$, you cannot know how many operations it will take on a computer. The underlying constant of O-notation could be 1000000 or 0.00001.

Comment: Asked on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301343/how-to-find-the-inverse-of-n-log-n (this is different than the question you link to).

Comment: A very related (indeed, equivalent) problem is addressed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\log n = x$ then $x = e^{\log n} \log n$ and so $\log n = W(x)$, where $W$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

The Lambert W functions is implemented in any popular mathematical software. It can be evaluated using standard techniques such as Newton's method or its second derivative generalization, Halley's method; see the Wikipedia article (under Numerical Evaluation).

Roughly speaking, $n = e^{W(x)} \approx e^{\log x - \log\log x} = x/\log x$. The Wikipedia article contains concrete bounds (under Asymptotic expansions).

Comment: Did you mean $x = e^{\log n} \log n$ ?

Comment: Thanks! There were also a few other mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

No way to say. $T(n) = O(n \log n)$ means there exist constants $c > 0, N_0$ so that for all $n \ge N_0$ it is $T(n) \le c n \log n$. They are *anything*, i.e., it might be valid only for ridiculously large $n$ (large $N_0$), or even for small $N_0$, like $N_0 = 10$, the constant $c$ could be such that all you know is that $T(100) \le \text{one milisecond}$ or $T(100) \le \text{one week}$.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being precise in my question text. The function/algorithm I'm talking about is $f(n) = nlog_2n$, thus the equation I'm trying to solve is $nlog_2n = 10^6$ where the $10^6$ is the amount of microseconds in a second. As stated in the question, we asume a computer that takes 1 microsecond for 1 operation. The $O(nlogn)$ is just a side note, the important thing is in the picture.